# Debugging javascript and web based applications

Tags: javascript, debugging

I am trying to get used to web development and one thing that eluded me as of late is debugging the code, specifically javascript code.  For example if I made a C++ program in visual studios and i said

```
for(INT i=0;i<10;i++)
{
//
}
```

It would through an error saying that it does not know what INT is(Maybe not ), and not run.  It appears to be in javascript, if something does not work, there is no way of seeing where and why.  Are there javascript debuggers where you can input the code into it to see if a variable is misspelled or something does not exist?

thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript errors should be logged in your browsers error console.

In Chrome go to View > Developer > Javascript Console

In Firefox go to Tools > Web Developer > Error Console

As an externally sourced debugger I recommend FireBug as it is an exceptional all-round html/css and javascript debugger which allows you to edit and preview code changes from within it.

[Link to Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)

Answer (score 0):

JSLint can help for some things before running your code.  Firebug, or the chrome equivalent as well as the IE developer tools (F12) are all great debuggers.